# How do I define multiple CSS background attributes?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to have those backgrounds work together?

```
background: url("../images/search.png") no-repeat scroll 9px 4px transparent;
background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #fdca14), color-stop(1, #ff8d02) );
background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #fdca14 0%, #ff8d02 100% );
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CSS**

```
.class{
    background: url("../images/search.png") no-repeat scroll 9px 4px transparent,-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #fdca14), color-stop(1, #ff8d02) ),-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #fdca14 0%, #ff8d02 100% );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[CSS3](http://css-tricks.com/stacking-order-of-multiple-backgrounds/) allows it. Here's an example of multiple background images being used in the same background:

```
.exampleClass {
    background-image: url(images/example1.png), url(images/example2.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat;
}
```

It's supported in [all major browsers](http://caniuse.com/multibackgrounds) (except for IE8 and before sadly)

Answer (score 3):

You may also want to check out [CSS3 Pie](http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/#pie-background) if you need to be able to do this in older IE browsers.